# Expression-bodied members for VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, properties

Does VB.NET support expression-bodied members?  So far, it seems to have everything in c# like null conditionals, nameof, interpolated strings, bodiless auto properties accessible only via ctor, etc.

In c#, the syntax is:

```
string FullName => FirstName + " " + LastName;
```

How can I achieve this in VB.NET?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, they are not currently supported in VB 14, only C# 6.

According to the table on the roslyn Github Wiki [Languages features in C# 6 and VB 14](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Languages-features-in-C%23-6-and-VB-14):

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------+--------+--------+
|                            Feature                            |  C# 6  |  VB 14 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+--------+--------+
| Auto-property initializers                                    | Added  | Exists |
| Read-only auto-properties                                     | Added  | Added  |
| Ctor assignment to getter-only autoprops                      | Added  | Added  |
| Static imports                                                | Added  | Exists |
| Index initializer                                             | Added  | No     |
| Await in catch/finally                                        | Added  | No     |
| Exception filters                                             | Added  | Exists |
| Partial modules                                               | N/A    | Added  |
| Partial interfaces                                            | Exists | Added  |
| Multiline string literals                                     | Exists | Added  |
| Year-first date literals                                      | N/A    | Added  |
| Comments after implicit line continuation                     | N/A    | Added  |
| TypeOf ... IsNot ...                                          | N/A    | Added  |
| Expression-bodied members                                     | Added  | No     |
| Null-conditional operators                                    | Added  | Added  |
| String interpolation                                          | Added  | Added  |
| nameof operator                                               | Added  | Added  |
| #pragma                                                       | Added  | Added  |
| Smart name resolution                                         | N/A    | Added  |
| Read-write props can implement read-only interface properties | Exists | Added  |
| #Region inside methods                                        | Exists | Added  |
| Overloads inferred from Overrides                             | N/A    | Added  |
| CObj in attributes                                            | Exists | Added  |
| CRef and parameter name                                       | Exists | Added  |
| Extension Add in collection initializers                      | Added  | Exists |
| Improved overload resolution                                  | Added  | N/A    |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: That's a shame.  It seems like they could have easily implemented it.  Oh well.  What's an extra 4 lines of code anyway

Comment: @oscilatingcretin 400% in this case ;)

Comment: I had tried C# when it first came out, and it was so lacking I gave up on it. I've come back to it in the past year or so, and it's finally robust enough, and even has enough extra features over VB that I am finding myself missing C# when I have to go back and do work on old VB projects. **sigh**

Comment: The link to the wiki is dead.